# Binding one value to checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, bind

i am getting swallowed by an issue.

I have this code currently

```
<div ng-repeat="list in ConnectivityDetails">
            <div class="connectivity">
                <div class="title">
                    Disable Connectivity??</div>
                <div class="decision">
                    <p style="float: left;">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="list.Connectivity"/>
                        <label for="Yes">
                        </label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="spans">Yes</span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="list.Connectivity"/>
                        <label for="No">
                        </label>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="spans">No</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**
*I am getting both the text boxes `checked` though the returning object is having only one value, how to bind `true` (Yes) for the checkbox and `false` (NO) for the other?*

**My Object Contains this:**

```
var data = [{PracticeID: "1",Connectivity: "true", LabKey: "2154879",PracticeKey: "ABNCJFUE", CloudServiceURL: "ABC215947"}]";
```

*I want to bind **Connectivity** value to one of the checkboxes*

Help!
Thank you

Comment: You would be talking about a radio input at that point yes?

Comment: @JamesKleeh Yeah almost! But if _myobject_ contains _false_ then _No_ should be checked, otherwise _True_ means _Yes_..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ymZdx/3/

So it should be:

```
           <p style="float: left;">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="list.Connectivity" />
                <label for="Yes">
                </label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="spans">Yes</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="list.Connectivity" ng-true-value="false" ng-false-value="true" />
                <label for="No">
                </label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="spans">No</span>
            </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts so far. But i need checkboxes at this level. and i am getting _true_ or _false_ from the object in `ng-repeat` directive. if possible then i will place a fiddle with the question.

Comment: Ok, you didn't say checkboxes were required. You should read the documentation - FYI (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.checkbox). Edited based on your comment.